# Get profile picture from my databse to display on php page

Tags: php, mysql

So I wanted to make a login system and I have uploaded a profile picture to one of the accounts and want to display it on the profile.php page.  I think what I'm doing here is right, but it doesn't work.

Here is the code html+php code:

```
<img src="
        <?php 
            echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["image"]);
        ?>
">
```

Screenshot of the database record.

[image: Screenshot of the profile with the image]

Notice that I have started the session with `session_start();` in a php segment higher up on the page.

The output on the console:
[image: Console]

Comment: `echo 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $_SESSION["image"]);`

Comment: It says you don't have the image index in your session. Are you sure that you are storing it in the session?

Answer (score 1):

Check in your browser console if the path to the image is ok if you have a broken link you got an error to load image source

After that check, via `var_dump`, if your session is set or variable in session is null

If you got image, you must encode your image like:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($_SESSION["image"] ).'"/>';
```

I recommend you, do not use htmlspecialchars for developing if you have an error (when you know, the image is saved or not, add htmlspecialchars after that you know, then image is shown properly use it), and it seems like then you do not have created a session, check it, with var_dump, if exist

**Edit:**

How are you loading data from DB with the image to the session with the index image?

I would first test if a session works and store data in it and load it.
Only try this if session work

```
// Start the session
session_start();

$_SESSION["image"] = "TEST"; // Add only test string
var_dump($_SESSION["image"]); // Check it
exit();
```

If works, then you see only white page with string `'TEST'` or `string(4) 'TEST'`, else if you got an error, session does not work

> Based on the error message that the server sent does not have an 'image'
>   index session created.

Then I would check whether you are pulling the correct data from the database then saving it to a session. How you load data from the database?

Comment: I have updated the main post with an screenshot of the console and the bit of the source code that covers the image

Comment: I am not sure of what you are meaning :/ I did however test with what you said without any access..

Comment: I did however got this in the console:

 http://localhost/websites/svajper/string(4) 404 (Not Found)

With the attachment to the network tab where it simply explained that it didn't work... 404 error

Comment: Check my update please below "How can you load data from DB with the image to the session?"